# For loop and if value of "a" to get "R"

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a code with the following the rule.

```
#Rule

if p[i] ≥ c[i], then a[i] = 1
if p[i] < c[i], then a[i] = 0

R = a[i]*p[i] + (1-a[i])*c[i]
```

There are p[i] and c[i] for all i = 1,2,3,4 with three sample sets.
These are the expected calculation for each **a** and **R** for each sample set.

[image: calculation]

Then, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = [100,20,40]
p2 = [30,110,30]
p3 = [250,33,28]
p4 = [50,90,135]

c1 = [70,80,40]
c2 = [65,190,120]
c3 = [120,33,80]
c4 = [50,75,200]

p = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
c = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

n = len(p)

storage_R = []
storage_a = []

for i in range(0,n):

    if p[i] >= c[i]:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0 

    R = a*p[i] + (1-a)*c[i]
    storage_a.append(a)
    storage_R.append(R)

T = np.array(storage_R).transpose()
```

However, the results are as follows.

```
storage_a = [1, 0, 1, 1]

storage_R = [[100, 20, 40], [65, 190, 120], [250, 33, 28], [50, 90, 135]]

T = array([[100,  65, 250,  50],
       [ 20, 190,  33,  90],
       [ 40, 120,  28, 135]])
```

The expected results are:

```
#expected result

storage_A = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
storage_R = [[100, 80, 40], [65, 190, 120], [250, 33, 80], [50, 90, 200]]

T = array([[100,  65, 250,  50],
          [ 80, 190,  33,  90],
          [ 40, 120,  80, 200]])
```

Can anyone help what needs to be revised on the code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use NumPy, you should use it to its full potential. This includes using its vectorized operations to avoid looping in python.

It looks like `p1`, `p2`, etc are the *columns* of your `p` array, so create that array:

```
>>> p = np.array([p1, p2, p3, p4]).T
[[100  30 250  50]
 [ 20 110  33  90]
 [ 40  30  28 135]]


>>> c = np.array([c1, c2, c3, c4]).T
[[ 70  65 120  50]
 [ 80 190  33  75]
 [ 40 120  80 200]]
```

Now, the `a` array is simply `p >= c`, converted to an integer (you don't even really need to convert it to an integer, because numpy treats True values as 1 and False values as 0)

```
>>> a = p >= c
[[ True False  True  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [ True False False False]]
```

If you really want `a` as an integer array, use

```
>>> a = (p >= c).astype(int)
[[1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```

Finally, do your calculation:

```
>>> R = a*p + (1-a)*c
[[100  65 250  50]
 [ 80 190  33  90]
 [ 40 120  80 200]]
```

---

Better yet, recognize that each element of `R` is simply the greater of the corresponding elements of `p` and `c`, so just use [`np.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), which gives the same result

```
>>> R = np.maximum(p, c)
```

---

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY27bsMwDEV3fgVHKVUNPezGHZyPMLoFHgS1QD1IIRwHqL/eIe146CCBPDq6l5b591bCuo6ZbtOM5ZFpwXjHQgDksMOrs9Z4a2o7AHkBwRrnrAkCggDf8BaMbxnUAnj/ZCk0A0DaQs7WtHtG2jI@GuNE8UK2EB4lpBVwhJwbbmYAxKBQFacpLupKziB5PoFPPejqC9I/IbGQWEgspF0AmsYyK9KvIWmAyJ8ILx2mF4xVvM8L/ahvuTtGmrWetXgifEPl3qM@HXYvb34vzvFvzI@siAuPit7rdX0C)